# Minimizing Complexity algorithm when Iterating on Java Collection

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, sonarqube, time-complexity

i have a scenario when i have a List of Object let assume :

```
List<A> listofAElements
```

A object has 3 fields startDate, endDate , and rate.
the demand is iterating on this list and whenever i find 2 elements who have the same startDate and endDate, i should only keep one in the list with rate = rate1 + rate2.

this is the simplet code i did to do this but Sonar comlains about it's complexity :

```
    public static void arrangeList(List<TauxPeriodesATDto> tauxPeriodesATDtos){

    for (int i =0 ; i < tauxPeriodesATDtos.size() ; i++  ){

        for (int j = tauxPeriodesATDtos.size() -1 ; j >= 0; j-- ){

            if (j != i){
                    boolean isStartDatesEquals = tauxPeriodesATDtos.get(i).getDateDebut().equals(tauxPeriodesATDtos.get(j).getDateDebut());
                    boolean isEndDatesEquals = tauxPeriodesATDtos.get(i).getDateFin().equals(tauxPeriodesATDtos.get(j).getDateFin());

                    if (isStartDatesEquals && isEndDatesEquals ) {
                        BigDecimal itauxPrime = tauxPeriodesATDtos.get(i).getTauxPrimeAT();
                        BigDecimal jTauxPrime = tauxPeriodesATDtos.get(j).getTauxPrimeAT();
                        BigDecimal sommeDesTaux = itauxPrime.add(jTauxPrime);
                        tauxPeriodesATDtos.get(i).setTauxPrimeAT(sommeDesTaux);
                        tauxPeriodesATDtos.remove(j);
                    }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

do you have any suggestions on a better way to do this ?

Comment: Sonar probably complains because you have more than 3 `if,for,while,else` in the function.
I would suggest looking if you can reduce the loops or if conditions. Or refactor the code using the Stream API of Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get O(n) time complexity if you'd use a `LinkedHashMap` whose keys are the periods formed by start and end date and whose values are the elements. Then you iterate over your list, put them into the map and if such an element already exists you just combine the two.

For a better understanding I'll provide a non-lambda/streaming version:

```
//Pair is org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair, you could also provide your own class
Map<Pair<Date, Date>, TauxPeriodesATDto> combined = new LinkedHashMap<>();

for( TauxPeriodesATDto element : tauxPeriodesATDtos ) {
  Pair<Date, Date> key = Pair.of( element.getDateDebut(), element.getDateFin() );
  TauxPeriodesATDto existing = combined.get( key );

  if( existing != null ) {
    //duplicate already exists, so combine the two
    existing.setTauxPrimeAT( existing.getTauxPrimeAT().add( element.getTauxPrimeAT() );
  } else {
    //no duplicate yet
    combined.put( key, element );
  }      
}

//due to the use of LinkedHashMap the order of elements should be preserved
List<TauxPeriodesATDto> resultList = new ArrayList<>( combined.values() );
```

A Java8 variant might look like this:

```
LinkedHashMap<Pair, Element> combined = tauxPeriodesATDtos.stream().collect( 
       Collectors.toMap( (element) -> Pair.of( element.getDateDebut(), element.getDateFin()), //create the key
                         Function.identity(), //just use the new element
                         (e,n) -> { e.setTauxPrimeAT( e.getTauxPrimeAT().add( n.getTauxPrimeAT() ); return e; }, //combine the elements and return the existing one
                         LinkedHashMap::new ) ); //use a LinkedHashMap

List<TauxPeriodesATDto> resultList = new ArrayList<>( combined.values() );
```

Comment: unfortunately we are using java 7, i first thought about sorting the list and then comparing eache element with the next but it is o(n2) colmexity too. thank you for the solution it works great

Comment: If you want to avoid using an external library - you could write a similar solution by implementing your own equals and hashcode in TauxPeriodesATDto for comparing the dates.

Comment: @younesmati Sorting the list and then comparing should have O(n log(n))  overall complexity: sorting is O(n log(n)), iterating and combining would be O(n). I also thought about that solution but I didn't know whether the original order should be preserved and doing it with a map would be O(n) anyways (iterating = O(n), map access = O(1)).

Comment: @Thomas yes i agree sorting and comparing is O(nlog(n)), the solution you introduced seems more appropriate, by the way in my case i don't need to preserve the orginial order so if there is a better solution with that in mind let me know ! and thank you for your help i appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

My thought point is what you are aiming (combine the rate of object where start and end date is same), this can be achieve by basic DP.

Just store each last iteration and compare it with current iteration, and if you already have similar dates then combine result.

Below I am sharing example which I tried.

**ProductVo.Java**

```
package com.stack;

import java.util.Date;

public class ProductVo {

    private Date startDate;
    private int rate;
    private Date endDate;

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public int getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public void setRate(int rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

}
```

**MainApp.Java**

```
package com.stack;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Map<Date, ProductVo> contains = new HashMap<>();
        List<ProductVo> list = new ArrayList<ProductVo>();

        ProductVo productVo1 = new ProductVo();
        productVo1.setStartDate(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("01/10/2017"));
        productVo1.setEndDate(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("02/10/2017"));
        productVo1.setRate(10);
        list.add(productVo1);

        ProductVo productVo2 = new ProductVo();
        productVo2.setStartDate(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("04/10/2017"));
        productVo2.setEndDate(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("04/10/2017"));
        productVo2.setRate(20);
        list.add(productVo2);

        ProductVo productVo3 = new ProductVo();
        productVo3.setStartDate(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("01/10/2017"));
        productVo3.setEndDate(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("02/10/2017"));
        productVo3.setRate(30);
        list.add(productVo3);

        list.forEach(v -> {

            if (contains.containsKey(v.getStartDate())) {

                ProductVo p = contains.get(v.getStartDate());
                if (p.getEndDate().equals(v.getEndDate())) {
                    System.out.println(v.getRate() + p.getRate());
                }
            }

            if (!contains.containsKey(v.getStartDate())) {
                contains.put(v.getStartDate(), v);
            }

        });
    }

}
```